# Excel: Equation for SUMIFS based on both text and dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several thousand rows of information in one sheet ("Trial Balances Consolidated"), which looks like the image below I would like to sum the value in column D for every row that contains the phrase "Allowance for doubtful accounts", and has one of three date values in Column A.  Those 3 date values are 3/1/2019, 3/1/2018, and 3/1/2017.  The following formula is resulting in a value of 0.  But it should retrieve a value of $4,000 if used in the example below.  How would you change this formula?

```
=SUMIFS('Trial Balances Consolidated'!D:D,'Trial Balances Consolidated'!C:C,"*"&"Allowance for Doubtful Accounts"&"*",'Trial Balances Consolidated'!A:A,AND(OR("3/1/2019","3/1/2018","3/1/2017"))
```

[image: Example Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap in SUMPRODUCT and do not use `AND` or `OR`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('Trial Balances Consolidated'!D:D,'Trial Balances Consolidated'!C:C,"*"&"Allowance for Doubtful Accounts"&"*",'Trial Balances Consolidated'!A:A,{"3/1/2019","3/1/2018","3/1/2017"}))
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, this works great. I just need to make one tweak that it won't allow.  Instead of writing the dates in quotes, I'd like to reference the cells that contain the dates.  SUMPRODUCT will not allow for that it appears

Comment: It only works if the criteria are in consecutive range.  Replace `{"3/1/2019","3/1/2018","3/1/2017"}` with the range reference, like `F1:F3`